# Can a basilisk turn another basilisk to stone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, monsters

Can a [basilisk](http://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/SRD:Basilisk) turn another basilisk to stone with its petrifying gaze?

If yes: then I imagine that around any basilisk herd there should be many petrified basilisks.

If no: then I'm thinking that one might be able to use the eyes of a slain basilisk to fashion goggles that would make one immune from petrifying gaze.

Answer (score 21):

## In *D&D 3.5*, *No*

The [basilisk](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/basilisk.htm) (*Monster Manual* 23-4) is *not* otherwise noted as *not* being immune to the petrifying gaze attacks of others of its kind, so a basilisk *is* immune to the petrifying gaze attacks of others of its kind as well as its *own* petrifying gaze. That is, the *Monster Manual* Glossary on [gaze](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#gaze) says, "A creature is immune to gaze attacks of others of its kind unless otherwise noted" (310), and the *Dungeon Master's Guide* Glossary adds, "A creature is immune to its own gaze attack" (294).<sup>1</sup>

## In *Pathfinder*, also *No*

The description of the universal monster ability [gaze attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Gaze-Su-) mirrors that of the *Monster Manual* for *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*. That game's [basilisk](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/magical-beasts/basilisk) is likewise not called out as specifically vulnerable to other basilisks' gazes.

### Avoiding and getting a stony gaze (or fist)

Immunity to petrification is difficult to acquire in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*; in core that's usually a special quality of the [angels](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/angel.htm) (*MM* 10-13) and [eladrins](https://web.archive.org/web/20161101211807/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/glossary&term=Glossary_dnd_eladrinsubtype&alpha=E) (*MM* 93-5), for example. Changing form so as to gain such a creature's traits is likely the easiest way to gain such an immunity. Immunity to petrification in *Pathfinder* is easily acquired for 8,000 gp from the on-the-nose-named [*amulet of proof against petrification*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/amulet-of-proof-against-petrification).

The [*eyes of petrification*](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#eyesofPetrification) (*DMG* 256) (98,000 gp; 0 lbs.) are a magic item in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* yet not *Pathfinder*, but, by way of consolation, *Pathfinder*'s feat [Cockatrice Strike](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/cockatrice-strike-combat) lets a warrior's attack turn foes into statues.

Neither magic item mentions basilisk eyes as necessary for their construction.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> While the *Monster Manual* Glossary on gaze (*MM* 309-10) recommends a creature effectively turn off its gaze attack by (I kid you not, basilisk fans) *wearing a veil*, the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on [gaze attacks](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#gazeAttacks) says that a creature with a gaze attack can turn it off and on (294). However, the *3.5* revision paid the *DMG* Glossary only scant attention (for example, the spell resistance entry refers to the *power word* spells as spells of the school of conjuration rather than enchantment), and the *Monster Manual* is, after all, the game's primary source for *monsters*, so a DM may reasonably rule that the *Monster Manual*'s correct in having a basilisk lack an on/off switch for its petrifying gaze.